# Как поменять кодировку выводимого текста

Tags: c++, json

Пытаюсь разобраться с чтением и выводом Json файлов в C++. При попытке вывода кириллицы пишет странные символы, как понимаю проблема в кодировке, но не могу найти решение этой проблемы. Помогите, пожалуйста.

**Вывод**

```
{
        "age" : 18,
        "profession" : "\ud98b\udce4\u5b72"
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <json/json.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    Json::Value people;

    std::ifstream people_file("people.json");
    people_file >> people;

    std::cout << people["Anna"] << "\n";
}
```

**people.json**

```
{
  "Anna": {
    "age": 18,
    "profession": "студент"
  },
  "Иван": {
    "age": "nineteen",
    "profession": "mechanic"
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Выясните, в какой кодировке работает консоль. 2) Преобразуйте строки в эту кодировку перед входом посредством библиотеки ICU или iconv.

Comment: Консоль ВСЕГДА выводит в CP866. И это только ASCII символы, 1 байт на символ. Windows использует расширенную кодировку 2+ байта на символ (для всех языков), где к примеру символ ASCII 'А' (65) имеет код 1040 (ANSI). Есть несколько вариантов. 1) Изменить кодировку в IDE и сразу писать в ASCII. 2) Функции перекодировки из ANSI в ASCII и обратно. Если вы используете смешанные данные, к примеру из интернет в кодировке не ASCII, то нужно функции перекодировки использовать. Иначе лучше в IDE установить 866 и ничего дополнительно не писать :)

Comment: Ну в общем вы в IDE пишите в ANSI или иной кодировке , а консоль выводит в только в ASCII. В SETLOCALE вроде не Russian нужно писать а Ru или Rus!